# Using Where clause in Group Join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Please Consider these 2 tables:

```
CategoryID            CategoryName            CategoryModel
-----------------------------------------------------------
1                     Book                       1
2                     Shoe                       2
3                     Glass                      1
```

and

```
SubCategoryID      SubCategoryName    CategoryID     SubCategoryModel    OtherColumn1       OtherColum2
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1                  Book1              1                   3
2                  Book2              1                   1
3                  Shoe1              2                   2
4                  Shoe2              2                   2
```

I want such this query:

```
from a in Category
join b in SubCategory
on a.CategoryID equals b.CategoryID into grpDetail
where a.CategoryModel != b.SubCategoryModel     <----------
select new 
{
     Id = a.CategoryID,
     Count1 = grpDetail.Count(o=>o.OtherColumn1 == 1),
     ...
}
```

the problem id I can't access to `b` in above specifies line. How can I write this query?

Thanks

Comment: You can have a look at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause?view=netframework-4.8#group-join) sample

Comment: what exactly do you want to have in your `select`, and what is your problem? it's very unclear what you want.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Use navigation properties. Don't join. It'll be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a straightforward one to many relation between Categories and SubCategories: every Category has zero or more SubCategories; every SubCategory belongs to exactly one Category, namely the Category that the foreign key SubCategory.CategoryId refers to.

You want to join Category and SubCategory on this foreign key. You don't want all Category-SubCategory combinations that match, you want only those where Category.CategoryModel is not equal to SubCategory.SubCategoryModel.

From the remaining records, you want to select several properties. I don't see property GrpDetail in your classes, so I don't know what you want.

Luckily you mention that your problem is in the Where:

```
var result = Categories.Join(SubCategories, // join tables Categories and SubCategories
    category => category.Id,                // from every category take the Id,
    subCategory => subCategory.CategoryId,  // from every subCategory take foreign key CategoryId

    (category, subCategory) => new          // when they match make one new object
    {
       // we need at least Category.CategoryModel and SubCategory.SubCategoryModel
       CategoryModel = category.CategoryModel,
       SubCategoryModel = subCategory.SubCategoryModel,

       // Select other Category properties that you plan to use:
       CategoryId = category.Id,
       ...

       // Select other SubCategory properties that you plan to use:
       ...
})
// we don't want all combinations, only those where
// CategoryModel is not equal to SubCategoryModel
.Where(joinResult => joinResult.CategoryModel != joinResult.SubCategoryModel)

// from the remaining combinations calculate the final result
.Select(joinResult => new
{
    Id = joinResult.CategoryId,
    Count1 = ... // sorry, don't know what property grpDetail does
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please write `LINQ` version?

Comment: Join and Select are very old functions. So I guess they are in all LINQ versions. I don't know when Lambda expressions were introduced in C#, but I think it almost 10 years now?

Answer (score 1):

split your query into 2, first do your join with the where clause and then do your group by.